Calling zero-sized, non-active union member's member function
I know that accessing non-active member of a union is UB, but what about invoking zero-sized and trivial union member's member function? Technically it is not accessing so I hope it is valid but I can't find the exact reference about it.
In other words, can [[no_unique_address]] be implemented with union before C++20 without EBO?
template<typename T>
struct MyVector {
  union {
    T* ptr{};

    // Just an example. Suppose that is_trivial<alloc> == true and is_empty_v<alloc> == true
    std::allocator<T> alloc; 
  }; 

  explicit MyVector(std::size_t size) {
    // Is this UB?
    ptr = alloc.allocate(size); 
  }
};



Pretty sure this make is UB: https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/basic.life#6.  Specifically 6.2

If the member function has no preconditions, it might be okay.  But that's a big if.  And it isn't obvious by casual inspection.  And if the compiler can warn about the (potential) issue, I would expect it to warn in this case.  And if there is a runtime sanitizer that squawks about this situation, I wouldn't be surprised that it would squawk even if this turns out to be an okay edge case.

Why would an empty class need none-static functions?

[basic.life]/7.2 makes calling any non-static member function on the object before its lifetime begins UB, regardless of any properties of the object or function.

In other words, can [[no_unique_address]] be implemented with union before C++20 without EBO?

[[no_unique_address]] can always be implemented conforming by simply ignoring it. It only gives the compiler more choices for object layout.
But you can't use a union to store two objects in their lifetime at the same address even if one object is empty and trivial. There are several other operations that require an object to actually be in its lifetime, not only member access.
